# How to access alfresco cloud repository using cmis?

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I am new to alfresco. I have alfresco cloud account and I want to access content in cloud repository. But I unable to figure out repository url for same.I need repository url format to connet to alfresco cloud account.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL for CMIS 1.0 and the AtomPub binding is:
https://api.alfresco.com/cmis/versions/1.0/atom

You may also be able to use CMIS 1.1, just change the version number. I believe the browser binding may now be supported on Alfresco in the cloud. To try it, just change /atom to /browser.

Alfresco in the cloud uses OAuth so you'll need to do the "OAuth dance" to exchange your API key and secret for a bearer token. There are multiple OAuth clients available that will work with Alfresco in the cloud. For an example of how to use the Google OAuth client you might want to look at [this project](https://code.google.com/p/alfresco-api-java-examples/) on Google Code.

If you don't have an Alfresco in the cloud API key you can get one for free from https://www.alfresco.com/develop/cloud/signup.

Comment: OpenCMIS has OAuth support since release 0.11.0.

See JavaDoc of the [OAuthAuthenticationProvider](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/chemistry/opencmis/tags/chemistry-opencmis-0.11.0/chemistry-opencmis-client/chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings/src/main/java/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/bindings/spi/OAuthAuthenticationProvider.java?revision=1587355) class for details.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I want to build application in PHP that will fetch content from alfresco cloud repository. now I have two questions
1) I need to use OAuth. can I get reference or idea how to do it in php.
2) While doing OAuth authentication we need to enter username and password. whose username and passwords?

Comment: There are likely many examples of doing OAuth with PHP available on the net. When your app attempts to talk to Alfresco in the cloud, Alfresco will display a login dialog. Your end-user will provide their Alfresco in the cloud username and password. If auth is successful, Alfresco will then redirect to your application using the URL you provided when you requested your API key. Your app will now have an access token and a refresh token. You can persist these. When the access token expires you can use the refresh token to get a new one, keeping your end-user from having to re-authenticate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understood the flow of authentication. But all end-users will not have an alfresco cloud username and password. Does the Enterprise edition and registering developer account with alfresco will make any difference to above authentication flow(means will not prompt end-use for login dialogue box)?
If not, Can we have authentication process that will always use only mentioned credentials without showing login dialogue box to end-user(that means it will be background process).

Comment: Enterprise Edition does not use OAuth, so you could use a service account pattern. But you'd have to run your own server. If you stick with Alfresco in the cloud each of your users will have to have their own accounts.

Comment: Hello Jeff, I am able to get the access token.But Now when I enter the Bearer [your access token] , it gives me
{
  "error":"invalid_request",
  "error_description":"Invalid access token"
}

this Response.


I am not able to find out what is the reason behind this.

Could you please let me know what could be the reason for such response?

Comment: You might want to try an example that is known to work. Try GetSitesExample.java in this project: https://code.google.com/p/alfresco-api-java-examples/. Remember that your access token expires from time-to-time and you'll need to use your refresh token to get a new one.